# Dynamic pagination with Jquery append - how to save location?

Tags: jquery, pagination

I'm using some javascript (Jquery) to dynamically paginate data on my website like all the cool kids do now (FB, Twitter). I like the way it looks, it's a nice reliable system, but it's always bugged me that if you append data by manipulating the DOM your location is gone if you leave the page. If it helps, here's what I use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page-link").live("click",function(){
        $(this).html("<img src='http://www.whatever.com/img/loading_small.gif' />");
        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split("?");
        var minlimit = splitid[1];
        var order = splitid[2];
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://www.whatever.com/php/selectAllWhatever.php?min="+minlimit+"&max=10&order="+order,
            data:"min="+minlimit+"&max=10",
            success:function(msg){
                $(".paging-bar").remove();
                $("#div").append(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

So say a user pages 40 results, clicks a link from the results to visit another page, and then comes back to find that all that paging they did is gone and they're back at the first 10 results. Not critical, but annoying either way. How can I retain their location in the paging results so when they come back they're where they left off? I've thought about trying to pass some get parameters to indicate paging location or leave a cookie, but I can't find a nice clean way to do it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it a couple ways : GET/POST, SESSION variable, or COOKIEs.

to use GET variables you would simply have to put a variable at the end of all your links, and handle those variables in all of your destination pages.  Your destination pages would then have to modify all of its links to carry that pagination variable.  Naturally, this is not the most elegant solution.

You could also do it in a session variable.  The code for this would look like:
php:

```
//This is in #selectAllWhaterver.php
session_start();

$_SESSION['paginationMin'] = $_POST['min'];
$_SESSION['paginationMax'] = $_POST['max'];

***********************************************
//Then in your php when you reload the page that has pagination on it
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['paginationMin'])
     $min = $_SESSION['paginationMin'];
else
     $min = 0;

if(isset($_SESSION['paginationMax'])
     $max = $_SESSION['paginationMax'];
else
     $max = 10;

//Now use these variables to generate wtv content you are loading
```

This is probably the most elegant solution, because it will save the pagination data for their session - meaning once they close their browser it resets.

If you would like to use cookies, which will stay alive even after the session dies, you would do it like this.  (Note: I'm no pro on cookies.  sorry if this is imperfect)

javascript:

```
document.cookie = "paginationMin="+minLimit;
document.cookie = "paginationMax=10";

//And to grab them again


 var cookies = ""+document.cookie;
 var pos = cookies.indexOf("paginationMax");
 var pos2 = cookies.indexOf(';', pos);

 var max =  unescape(cookies.substring(pos+cookieName.length+1,pos2));

 var pos = cookies.indexOf("paginationMin");
 var pos2 = cookies.indexOf(';', pos);

 var min =  unescape(cookies.substring(pos+cookieName.length+1,pos2));
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't really think about just setting a session - good solution! Thanks for the help.